# Which DNNClassifier to use?

Tags: tensorflow

This question has been asked in two of the previous posts. However, they still remain unanswered. Given that we have

tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier and
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier

which one should be preferred, The estimator DNNClassifier does not have the traditional "fit" method.

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3860/tensorflow-tf-contrib-dnnclassifier-or-tf-estimator-dnnclassifier/4269
[What is the difference between tf.estimator.Estimator and tf.contrib.learn.Estimator in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204897/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-estimator-estimator-and-tf-contrib-learn-estim)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between tf.estimator.Estimator and tf.contrib.learn.Estimator in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204897/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-estimator-estimator-and-tf-contrib-learn-estim)

Answer (score -1):

Alway prefer tf.estimator.DNNClassifier, which is a more stable public interface.