# The fit function from tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor asks to switch to tf.train.get_global_step

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to get a `LinearRegressor` to work and I get an error for which there doesn't seem to be much documentation about.

When I do:

```
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=linear_features)

regressor.fit(input_fn=training_input_fn, steps=10000)

regressor.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

I get the error:

> Instructions for updating: Please switch to tf.train.get_global_step

I am not sure how to proceed.

I read from the docs:

> SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED. They will be removed after 2016-12-01.
>   Instructions for updating: Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn
>   interface by moving into separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and
>   batch_size are only available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will
>   only accept input_fn. Example conversion: est = Estimator(...) -> est
>   = SKCompat(Estimator(...))

But I'm not sure to what I should change to, or how to switch to the global step.

I tried using `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` mainly because I'm out of ideas, and did something like this:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=linear_features)

estimator.train(input_fn=training_input_fn)
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
estimator.predict(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

But got no output at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Instructions for updating: Please switch to tf.train.get_global_step

Actually, this is not an error, but a warning. It's logged exactly because you're using `contrib` package (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44204897/712995), short summary: it's deprecated).

You should switch to the core `tf.estimator` API and that includes everything:

- `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` instead of `tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor`
- `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` instead of `tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn`
- `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` instead of `tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column`
- ...

---

The reason for not seeing anything with the new `Estimator` is likely due to `eval_input_fn` function. Make sure you specify `num_epochs=1`, otherwise it will loop over the data set again and again during evaluation.